# Command to install Drupal 9 with Composer

Tags: composer, 9

The latest version of Drupal 8 can be installed via Composer with the following command:

```
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project mynewproject
```

What is the equivalent command to install the latest version of Drupal 9 (beta1)?

Comment: Did you try using a tag? https://github.com/drupal/recommended-project/releases

Comment: There is a docs page at https://www.drupal.org/docs/9/install-drupal-9

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`create-project` can take a version number, and recommended-project has some [tags in for 9.x](https://github.com/drupal/recommended-project/tree/9.0.0-beta1), so for example:

```
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project mynewproject "9.0-beta1"
```

Or if you just want the bleeding edge to play with:

```
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project mynewproject "^9.0" --stability=dev --prefer-dist
```

Comment: I see that you edited your reply and made it clearer that the version number in the `create-project` command is for recommended-project, and not drupal/core-recommended - great! Do you know if the maintainers of recommended-project plans to create a release/tag for all Drupal versions? If not, we can't expect to be able to install a specific Drupal version using create-project.

Comment: I can't vouch for it @hansfn, but my understanding is that `drupal/recommended-project` is to be tagged in sync with the Drupal project itself. So you should expect to see complementary tags for all releases

Comment: Thank you again Clive.  I'd check the documentation for the create-project command but I was looking for the answer in the options.  I didn't notice that the example command includes a tag.

Comment: drupal/recommended-project is maintained within drupal core itself, and then generated as a subtree split of drupal by drupal's infrastructure. There will not be any versions of drupal prior to 8.8.0 there, because it didnt exist before then, and thus is not possible, but all future versions are automatically created as part of the infrastructure packaging workflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project` it will now install D9